# What exactly happens when we open a Vi editor on a shell

Tags: linux, bash, vi

When we write the command `vi <filename>` what exactly happens - there is no new window being opened for it, it seems that it certainly enters into some other mode out of the **shell**. And when we get out of `vi` we return back to the shell.

Does it use hashing to check whether the `<filename>` is already present or not and if:

- It is not present in the directory entered by the user it uses `create` system call to reserve space on disk.
- If it exists then it uses system call `open`.

Apart from this does it happens with all the text editors like `nano` & `emacs`?

Comment: You seem to confuse several different issues here. It isn't clear what you mean by "allocates the space & the layout". As for mode, vi switches *the terminal* (a window or a physical device) to a special mode designed for full-screen programs (that's in terms of a single text terminal screen mind you). Upon exit it switches it back to the normal mode designed for line-by-line input/output.

Comment: @n.m. I have changed the question a bit, please check it again.

Comment: This question is **much** too broad to be answerable. If you're only asking if space for your file is reserved when an editor is first started, before the editor is actually instructed to save the file -- the answer is generally "no". But it's not remotely clear whether that *is* what you're asking: The question is too fuzzy to provide a concrete, canonical and complete answer.

Comment: Similarly, "does it use hashing to check[...]" is a filesystem detail; the editor doesn't know anything about how the filesystem's directory structure is implemented: Some use hash trees, some just use lists that require an O(n) traversal, etc.

Comment: (For that matter, `create` isn't always its own system call -- in many places, there's just an `O_CREAT` flag to the `open` syscall).

Comment: I suggest this book: "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" from  W. Richard Stevens and Stephen A. Rago.

Comment: Everything a developer wants to know about `vim` is on [GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vi` uses the terminal (actually, [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)). It is a tty, in Unix parlance. Read [*The TTY Demystified*](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/), [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) (for `/dev/tty`), [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) ([pseudoterminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal)).

It uses some terminal library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), built above [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). See also [ioctl_tty(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) (actually `vim` don't use `ncurses`, just the lower level `libtinfo` related to [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/))

> it seems that it certainly enters into some other mode out of the shell.

That is not a mode of the shell, but of the tty (dealt with the terminal emulator). [ANSI escapes codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are also relevant.

See also [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html).

Terminal IO is not only buffered in the libc, but also in the kernel. Read about [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline).

Regarding editing a file, `vi` works like most [text editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor), it maintains a data structure in memory describing the current content of a buffer and work on that structure in memory. The content is written to the file (using file related system calls like [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html)) only when you save the buffer.

BTW, [`vim`](http://vim.org/) is free software (or open source), so download and study its [source code](https://www.vim.org/git.php) of `vim`. And [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) are also free software.

Take time to read some good Linux system programming book (like the old [ALP](https://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf) or something newer) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Notice that terminal IO is quite complex in the details (because [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) such as [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) or [VT220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT220) were complex). So you probably want to use a library like `ncurses` (or perhaps [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html))

BTW, in 2023, consider using a [graphical user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) (e.g. [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(protocol)) display servers) with open source editors using some open source graphical [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits). Recent variants of `vim` or [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) etc enable you to use the mouse and various fonts and [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting).